# Something went wrong. To try again, reload the page and then start the workflow, error on starting a workflow

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-server

i have already create a custom workflow with sharepoint designer and checked for error and it seem fine.
i published it on my document library so apprear the first issue : the column that contain the name of my workflow apprear and the link to start my workflow(contain the name of my first stap) doesn't appear.
the second problem is that when i tried to start the workflow manually on a specific document i get an alert : **Something went wrong. To try again, reload the page and then start the workflow**

i tried :
-restart service bus message broker
-restart service bus gateway
-recycle workflowMgntpool
-flushed the dsn resolver cache 
and the problem still occure

on uls log viewer it seems to be an error on w3wp.exe process

Comment: the workflow history is empty